How to create custom g-code functions in Codesys CNC?
I want to create a custom g-code like Gxx for switching on/off a PLC output. I need it because once G41 or G42 activated for tool radius correction the function block SMC_ToolRadiusCorr does not allow anything like M functions that stops preprocessing.
N10 GXX              --> Switch ON PLC output 
N20 G01 X100 Y100 F100
N30 G01 X0 Y0 F100
G30 GYY              --> Switch OFF PLC output

